# Create a table with generated columns

Tags: mysql, sql

We try to create a table with generated columns.

Please see these queries for our current table structure:

**Table Heepsy:**

```
CREATE TABLE `Heepsy` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `photo_url` varchar(300) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `followers` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `engagement` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=51731 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin;
```

**Table HypeAuditor:**

```
CREATE TABLE `HypeAuditor` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `engaement` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Country` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `Country_percentage` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Interest1` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `Interest1_percentage` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Interest2` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `Interest2_percentage` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Interest3` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `Interest3_percentage` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=27123 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**Table NinjaOutreach:**

```
CREATE TABLE `NinjaOutreach` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `fullname` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `photo_url` varchar(300) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `followers` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `engagement` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `category_1` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `category_2` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `category_3` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `category_4` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `category_5` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `category_6` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=296788 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin;
```

**Table Kombiniert:**

```
CREATE TABLE `Kombiniert` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `fullname` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `followers_heepsy` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `followers_ninjaoutreach` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `followers_average` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `engagement_heepsy` decimal(5,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `engagement_ninjaoutreach` decimal(5,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `engagement_hypeauditor` decimal(5,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `engagement_average` decimal(5,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `category1` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `category2` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `category3` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `category4` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `category5` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `category6` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `follower_interest1` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `follower_interest1_share` decimal(5,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `follower_interest2` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `follower_interest2_share` decimal(5,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `follower_interest3` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `follower_interest3_share` decimal(5,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `follower_country` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `follower_country_share` decimal(5,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `follower_country_total` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `follower_country_engaged` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

1. How do we need to update the SQL query to create the table `Kombiniert` with the following generated columns:

**followers_average:**
Average of columns "followers_heepsy" and "followers_ninjaoutreach" but only if both are greater than 0. If only one column is greater than 0, use the value of this column.

**engagement_average:**
Average of columns "engagement_heepsy" and "engagement_ninjaoutreach" and "engagement_hypeauditor" but only if all are greater than 0. If only two columns are greater than 0, use the average of these 2 columns. If only one column is greater than 0, use the value of this column.

**follower_country_total:**
followers_average * follower_country_share

**follower_country_engaged:**
followers_country_total * engagement_average

All generated columns should be STORED not virtual?

2. How do we need to create an `INSERT` query, which will do the following:

   For each `username` FROM `HypeAuditor` create a row with the following data in table `Kombiniert`:

   https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qU0WaExjg8cCsA3cdDvKf3UqdLxqXKw_8QnDRLvJwMA/edit?usp=sharing ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It would greatly help your question if you could include the table structure and data directly in the question as _text_, not as hyperlinks.

Comment: also - I think you mean calculated columns rather than generated. The columns themselves seem to be fixed but you want to insert calculated aggregates - am I right?

Comment: your table creation references InnoDB which I think is MySQL - correct?

Comment: Hi @iainc
thanks for your answer. Yes it is MySQL.

Comment: Hi @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for your answer. Have added MySQL as tag.

Comment: Hi @iainc - Yes right the columns are fixed.

Comment: Hi @TimBiegeleisen - I have tried to add everything directly in the question without links, I'm not sure How I can create the last table in the question.

Comment: Oh - some sample data and an expected output is also helpful.

Comment: Is a view what you mean? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/views.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I am presuming a join on username and a single record for each username in each table.

```
    INSERT INTO Kombiniert
(username, fullname, followers_heepsy, followers_ninjaoutreach, followers_average, engagement_heepsy, engagement_ninjaoutreach, engagement_hypeauditor, engagement_average, city, state, country, category1, category2, category3, category4, category5, category6, follower_interest1, follower_interest1_share, follower_interest2, follower_interest2_share, follower_interest3, follower_interest3_share, follower_country, follower_country_share, follower_country_total, follower_country_engaged)
    Select bb.*, follower_country_total*engagement_average as follower_country_engaged from
        (
            Select aa.*, followers_average*follower_country_share as follower_country_total from 
            (
                select 
                h.username,
                nj.fullname,
                hy.followers as followers_heepsy,
                nj.followers as followers_ninjaoutreach,
                case when (hy.followers=0 or hy.followers is null) and nj.followers>0 then nj.followers
                when hy.followers>0 and (nj.followers=0 or nj.followers is null) then hy.followers
                else (hy.followers+nj.followers)/2 end as followers_average,
                hy.engagement/100 as engagement_heepsy,
                nj.engagement/100 as engagement_ninjaoutreach,
                h.engagement/100 as engagement_hypeauditor,
                case    when (hy.engagement/100=0 or hy.engagement is null) and (nj.engagement/100=0 or nj.engagement is null) and h.engagement/100>0 then h.engagement/100
                        when (hy.engagement/100=0 or hy.engagement is null) and nj.engagement/100>0 and (h.engagement/100=0 or h.engagement is null) then nj.engagement/100
                        when hy.engagement/100>0  and (nj.engagement/100=0  or nj.engagement is null) and (h.engagement/100=0 or h.engagement is null) then hy.engagement/100
                        when (hy.engagement/100=0 or hy.engagement is null) and nj.engagement/100>0 and h.engagement/100>0 then (h.engagement/100+nj.engagement/100)/2
                        when hy.engagement/100>0  and nj.engagement/100>0 and (h.engagement/100=0 or h.engagement is null) then (hy.engagement/100+nj.engagement/100)/2
                        when hy.engagement/100>0  and (nj.engagement/100=0 or nj.engagement is null) and h.engagement/100>0 then (h.engagement/100+nj.engagement/100)/2
                        else (hy.engagement/100+nj.engagement/100+h.engagement/100)/3 end as engagement_average,
                nj.city,
                nj.state,
                nj.country ,
                nj.category_1,
                nj.category_2,
                nj.category_3,
                nj.category_4,
                nj.category_5,
                nj.category_6,
                h.interest1,
                h.Interest1_percentage/100 as follower_interest_share1,
                h.interest2,
                h.Interest2_percentage/100 as follower_interest_share2,
                h.interest3,
                h.Interest3_percentage/100 as follower_interest_share3,
                h.country as follower_country,
                h.country_percentage/100 as follower_country_share


                from HypeAuditor h
                left join Heepsy hy on h.username = hy.username
                left join NinjaOutreach nj on nj.username=h.username
                ) aa 
            ) bb
```

Comment: Hi @iainc thanks for your answer!

By doing so I get this error:
`Unknown column 'h.engagement' in 'field list'`

Comment: you misspelled engagement in the hypeauditor table - I corrected it in my version :-) You have engaement...

Comment: Ah thanks, have updated it. Now I get the following error: `Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`

Comment: OK - updated - forgot that the insert would try to populate the ID column.

Comment: Awesome - Thanks for this. Now I've run the query and get the following error: `Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'Beauty & Fashion'`

I think this is because of the `h.interest1/100 as follower_interest_share1` because `HypeAuditor.interest1`is a VARCHAR column, the column to calculate with is `HypeAuditor.Interest1_percentage`

Comment: This was awesome thank you so much @iainc - There was just a problem in the second case, I have corrected it and posted the code as answer to this thread.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked a bit with the answer from @ianic and come out to this result:

```
INSERT INTO Kombiniert
(username, fullname, followers_heepsy, followers_ninjaoutreach, followers_average, engagement_heepsy, engagement_ninjaoutreach, engagement_hypeauditor, engagement_average, city, state, country, category1, category2, category3, category4, category5, category6, follower_interest1, follower_interest1_share, follower_interest2, follower_interest2_share, follower_interest3, follower_interest3_share, follower_country, follower_country_share, follower_country_total, follower_country_engaged)
    Select bb.*, follower_country_total*engagement_average as follower_country_engaged from
        (
            Select aa.*, followers_average*follower_country_share as follower_country_total from 
            (
                select 
                h.username,
                nj.fullname,
                hy.followers as followers_heepsy,
                nj.followers as followers_ninjaoutreach,
                case when hy.followers=0 and nj.followers>0 then nj.followers
                when hy.followers>0 and nj.followers=0 then hy.followers
                else (hy.followers+nj.followers)/2 end as followers_average,
                hy.engagement/100 as engagement_heepsy,
                nj.engagement/100 as engagement_ninjaoutreach,
                h.engagement/100 as engagement_hypeauditor,
                case    when hy.engagement/100=0 and nj.engagement/100=0 and h.engagement/100>0 then h.engagement/100
                        when hy.engagement/100=0 and nj.engagement/100>0 and h.engagement/100=0 then nj.engagement/100
                        when hy.engagement/100>0 and nj.engagement/100=0 and h.engagement/100=0 then hy.engagement/100
                        when hy.engagement/100=0 and nj.engagement/100>0 and h.engagement/100>0 then (h.engagement/100+nj.engagement/100)/2
                        when hy.engagement/100>0 and nj.engagement/100>0 and h.engagement/100=0 then (hy.engagement/100+nj.engagement/100)/2
                        when hy.engagement/100>0 and nj.engagement/100=0 and h.engagement/100>0 then (h.engagement/100+nj.engagement/100)/2
                        else (hy.engagement/100+nj.engagement/100+h.engagement/100)/3 end as engagement_average,
                nj.city,
                nj.state,
                nj.country ,
                nj.category_1,
                nj.category_2,
                nj.category_3,
                nj.category_4,
                nj.category_5,
                nj.category_6,
                h.interest1,
                h.Interest1_percentage/100 as follower_interest_share1,
                h.interest2,
                h.Interest2_percentage/100 as follower_interest_share2,
                h.interest3,
                h.Interest3_percentage/100 as follower_interest_share3,
                h.country as follower_country,
                h.country_percentage/100 as follower_country_share


                from HypeAuditor h
                left join Heepsy hy on h.username = hy.username
                left join NinjaOutreach nj on nj.username=h.username
                ) aa 
            ) bb
```

So far it works fine, except for one thing:
There are usernames in `HypeAuditor` only exists in one of the tables `Heepsy` OR `NinjaOutreach`. If this is the case, there is `NULL` inserted into the columns from this specific table, which is fine so far, but the two cases to calculate the average are not working then.

How can I modify the cases to work in this case also?

Comment: see my answer again - I have updated to add in a test for NULL

Comment: Hi @iainc - Thanks for this, the problem was something else. As I've found out yesterday the line `when hy.engagement/100>0  and (nj.engagement/100=0 or nj.engagement is null) and h.engagement/100>0 then (h.engagement/100+nj.engagement/100)/2` has some mistake in it because you check for `nj.engagement is null` but you're calculating with `nj.engagement` in the end. I have changed the average calculation to `hy.engagement` which is doing fine then :)

Comment: Btw, do you maybe know some way to make this query more efficient for large tables, because my tables `Heepsy`, `HypeAuditor` and `NinjaOutreach` have hundred thousands of rows?

Comment: OK, first i would run the query with an without the Case statements to see if they are creating a huge problem. You could also review indexing. You are going to want a clustered index on username in each table and then some non-clustered indexes on username / engagement.

Comment: You might also benefit from doing the main insert first then running an update query to add follower_country_engaged and follower_country_total

Answer (score 0):

Just found the final answer with the help of @ianic awesome query! Thank you so much!

Here it is:

```
INSERT INTO Kombiniert
(username, fullname, followers_heepsy, followers_ninjaoutreach, followers_average, engagement_heepsy, engagement_ninjaoutreach, engagement_hypeauditor, engagement_average, city, state, country, category1, category2, category3, category4, category5, category6, follower_interest1, follower_interest1_share, follower_interest2, follower_interest2_share, follower_interest3, follower_interest3_share, follower_country, follower_country_share, follower_country_total, follower_country_engaged)
    Select bb.*, follower_country_total*engagement_average as follower_country_engaged from
        (
            Select aa.*, followers_average*follower_country_share as follower_country_total from 
            (
                select 
                h.username,
                nj.fullname,
                hy.followers as followers_heepsy,
                nj.followers as followers_ninjaoutreach,
                case when hy.followers IS NULL AND nj.followers>0 THEN nj.followers
                when hy.followers>0 AND nj.followers IS NULL THEN hy.followers
                else (hy.followers+nj.followers)/2 end as followers_average,
                hy.engagement/100 as engagement_heepsy,
                nj.engagement/100 as engagement_ninjaoutreach,
                h.engagement/100 as engagement_hypeauditor,
                case    when hy.engagement IS NULL AND nj.engagement IS NULL AND h.engagement>0 THEN h.engagement/100
                        when hy.engagement IS NULL AND nj.engagement>0 AND h.engagement IS NULL THEN nj.engagement/100
                        when hy.engagement>0 AND nj.engagement IS NULL AND h.engagement IS NULL THEN hy.engagement/100
                        when hy.engagement IS NULL AND nj.engagement>0 AND h.engagement>0 THEN (h.engagement/100+nj.engagement/100)/2
                        when hy.engagement>0 AND nj.engagement>0 AND h.engagement IS NULL THEN (hy.engagement/100+nj.engagement/100)/2
                        when hy.engagement>0 AND nj.engagement IS NULL AND h.engagement>0 THEN (h.engagement/100+hy.engagement/100)/2
                        else (hy.engagement/100+nj.engagement/100+h.engagement/100)/3 end as engagement_average,
                nj.city,
                nj.state,
                nj.country ,
                nj.category_1,
                nj.category_2,
                nj.category_3,
                nj.category_4,
                nj.category_5,
                nj.category_6,
                h.interest1,
                h.Interest1_percentage/100 as follower_interest_share1,
                h.interest2,
                h.Interest2_percentage/100 as follower_interest_share2,
                h.interest3,
                h.Interest3_percentage/100 as follower_interest_share3,
                h.country as follower_country,
                h.country_percentage/100 as follower_country_share


                from HypeAuditor h
                left join Heepsy hy on h.username = hy.username
                left join NinjaOutreach nj on nj.username=h.username
                ) aa 
            ) bb
```